# MYSQL multiselect with subselect in where

Tags: mysql

Hi I have the following tables:

1. `user` with colums `id, first_name, last_name, etc...`
2. `meeting` with colums `id, meeting_name, etc...`
3. `enroled` with colums `id, user, meeting, enrol_date, disenrol_date`

When user do enrol to meeting, I create a new row in the table `enroled` with `id`, `user_id` and `enrol_date` (timestamp)
and when user do disenrol I write timestapmp of disenrol to `disenrol_date` column.
(but when user do enrol->disenrol->enrol = I have 2 rows in table `enroled`)

I need select all user when not enroled to meeting (I have it in first section of where) and all user disenroled form all row of this meeting(All rows of the user for that meeting have a disenrol column filled in).

Actual I have:

```
SELECT user.id, user.last_name, user.first_name
FROM user
WHERE 
    // not enroled
    user.id NOT IN 
            (SELECT enroled.user FROM enroled 
                    WHERE enroled.meeting='".$res['id']."'
                    GROUP BY enroled.user)

    AND
    // full_disenroled
    /// I dont understand how this spec.

ORDER BY user.Last_name ASC
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide sample data and a desired output based on it. [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/1920232)